# Tracking the movement of beetles

Tags: tracking

I have a video of showing black beetles moving across a white surface. I want to create movement tracks of these beetles to study how they move to search for food (linear, curved etc). Can I use Blender to assign a dot to a beetle and then have it record the movement as a line?

Comment: search here for question with "tracking" and "video sequencer". or on google with additional "tutorial"

Comment: sure you can, but depends on the video material you have too... you would use single tracks so it's a lot easier than having to reconstruct the scene or solve the camera... but depending on things like the scale  and speed of those beetles or if they cluster or lump together things would need more manual work... maybe show us some frames of your video?